# How to use Azure CLI to configure or manage deployment slots in ARM mode

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-rm-template

Looks like Azure Powershell has option of slots but ARM mode of Azure CLI is missing these capabilities.

1. How to setup an ARM template to create a deployment slot?
2. How to use Azure CLI to deploy an ARM template for a specific slot

Reference:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `$ azure group deployment create` is missing the slot option but it's present in `$ azure webapp create <resource-group> <name> --slot <slot-name> -l <location> -p <server-farm-plan-id>`.

May be we should create webapp first and then use regular ARM template to update a particular slot by specifying parameter value webSiteName =  in following ARM template parameters file.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-java-tomcat/azuredeploy.parameters.json